# Sharepoint Drive Mapping, The network name cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint, mappeddrive

Over the weekend the UPS that controls our core switch decided to die, after sorting everything out Monday morning I have been left with a problem I just can't get to the bottom of.

We can no longer map our Sharepoint to a network drive or "open in explorer" any page on the sharepoint. Acessing it via our intranet page works fine though. If I attempt with or without specifing a password I get the same error

```
System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found.
```

I've tried restarting the webclient service even disabling rebooting and enabling and rebooting the Desktop Experience feature so I'm pretty sure it's not a webdav issue. There aren't any helpful clues I can find in the event viewer.

No other changes have happened recently.

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

J